# Accessing a file outside public_html

Tags: php

I am trying to create  a php login script so that my index.php is in pubic_html and qustinaire.php is outside so it cannot be accessable directly by url. I thought index.php should have access so that I could use header("location:login_success.php") but I am failing. how can I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

```
Files
| - public_html
    | - index.php
| - qustinaire.php
| - login_success.php
```

to reach login_success.php from index.php

```
header("location:../login_success.php");
```

or another option is:

```
header($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/login_success.php";
```

DOCUMENT_ROOT will return the path from the root:

```
/var/users/homepages/USER_ID/
```

Comment: You are welcome. Don't forget to accept, if it worked.